# Scala Migrations mysql support

Tags: scala, migration, adapter

I have a problem with the [scala-migrations](http://code.google.com/p/scala-migrations/) project. They state in the documentation that they currently support     * Derby * MySQL * Oracle * PostgreSQL, but I have searched a bit and have found no support for MySQL. There is no MySQLDatabaseAdapter there. I can see all the others but not this one. Does anyone have a clue on this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a quick glance through the source code, it doesn't seem like MySQL is actually supported. Neither the Vendor object:

http://code.google.com/p/scala-migrations/source/browse/src/main/scala/com/imageworks/migration/Vendor.scala

nor the DatabaseAdapter object:

http://code.google.com/p/scala-migrations/source/browse/src/main/scala/com/imageworks/migration/DatabaseAdapter.scala

seem to know anything about a MySQL option.